# How to join two queries while keeping "City" as common filter for first column

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to join these two separate queries. Each of them on its own works. One is for 2019 and one is for 2018.. I am trying to have 7 total columns. The first being "city" which is where the two queries both share and then 6 more columns (3 for 2019 & 3 for 2018). Thank you for your help!

I've tried using join and union, but I believe my syntax is off

```
select  coalesce(city, 'Total') as "City", 
    sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2019 AAA",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2019 BBB",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as "2019 CCC"
    from reservations
        join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
        where status = 'YYYY' 
        and city <> 'XXXX'
        and reservations.deleted_at is null
            group by rollup(city)
            order by city asc;



select  coalesce(city, 'Total') as "City", 
    sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2018 AAA",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as "2018 BBB",
    sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as "2018 CCC"
    from reservations
        join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
        where guesty_status = 'YYYY' 
        and city <> 'XXXX'
        and reservations.deleted_at is null
            group by rollup(city)
            order by city asc;
```

Comment: These 2 queries are the same. How can they return different results?

Comment: Use every query as a table expression in a join. First remove `;` and `order by ..` from both.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use each query as a derived table:

```
select 
    City, 
    [2019 AAA], 
    [2019 BBB], 
    [2019 CCC], 
    [2018 AAA], 
    [2018 BBB], 
    [2018 CCC]
from (

    select  coalesce(city, 'Total') as [City], 
        sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as [2019 AAA],
        sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as [2019 BBB],
        sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as [2019 CCC]
        from reservations
            join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
            where status = 'YYYY' 
            and city <> 'XXXX'
            and reservations.deleted_at is null
                group by rollup(city)
    ) as t2019
join (
    select  coalesce(city, 'Total') as [City], 
        sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as [2018 AAA],
        sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee)/sum(reservations.number_of_nights) as [2018 BBB],
        sum(reservations.accommodation_fare+reservations.cleaning_fee) as [2018 CCC]
        from reservations
            join listings on reservations.listings_id = listings.id
            where guesty_status = 'YYYY' 
            and city <> 'XXXX'
            and reservations.deleted_at is null
                group by rollup(city)
) as t2018
on t2018.City = t2019.City
order by City;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the two queries are essentially the same, except that one has data for 2018 and one has data for 2019.  I would suggest adding the year as a column (and removing the year from your existing column names) and then performing a UNION ALL to join them.

```
SELECT [City], 2018 as [Year of Data], [AAA], [BBB], [CCC]
FROM ...  -- finish this with the 2018 query stuff.

UNION ALL

SELECT [City], 2019 as [Year of Data], [AAA], [BBB], [CCC]
FROM ...  -- finish this with the 2019 query stuff.
```

Now, I suspect that these two queries can actually be rewritten as a single query, but since I don't actually see any difference in the two queries except the artificial column naming ([2018 AAA] vs [2019 AAA]) I can't be certain that you're not running this query against two separate databases; one for 2018 and one for 2019.